# RMarkdown Kable width issues

Tags: r-markdown

I am trying to create a table to hold some basic information using Kable in RMarkdown that will be generated in HTML, PDF, and Word. Here is the code I have

````
---
title: "test"
author: ''
date: "2015/03/24"
output:
 pdf_document:
 keep_tex: yes  
---

```{r kable1, echo=FALSE}
Variable <- c("VAR1", "VAR2", "VAR3", "VAR4")
Label <- c("LABEL", "A very       loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo     ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo nnnnnnngggggggg label yall", "LAB3", "LAB4")
Classification <- c("Type1", "Type2", "Type1", "Type1")
data <- data.frame(Variable, Label, Classification)
library(knitr)
kable(data)
```

```{r kable2, echo=FALSE}
Variable <- c("VAR1", "VAR2", "VAR3", "VAR4")
Label <- c("LABEL", "LabLE", "LAB3", "LAB4")
Classification <- c("Type1", "Type2", "Type1", "Type1")
data <- data.frame(Variable, Label, Classification)
library(knitr)
kable(data)
```
````

The HTML output is as follows. [image]
This is what I want. I like how the table fills out the html. However, when I produce PDF I get the following. [image]

As we can see there are issues with the PDF, the first table runs off the page and the second does not fill up the entire width. I am, unfortunately, a n00b when it comes to R, Kable, and RMarkdown. Is there a way to set options on the kable table so that the PDF looks as nice as the HTML in terms of page placement and width? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LaTeX will not break the long lines inside of a table cell for you -- or you should use a custom environment for that, which can be sometimes really frustrating when writing markdown to be processed by Pandoc. That's why I came up with the idea to break long lines inside of the cells before transforming to markdown via the [pander package](http://rapporter.github.io/pander/#markdown-tables). Quick example:

```
> pander(data, split.cells = 30, split.table = Inf)

-------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Variable                      Label                      Classification 
---------- --------------------------------------------- ----------------
   VAR1                        LABEL                          Type1      

   VAR2                       A very                          Type2      
           loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo                 
              ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo                    
                    nnnnnnngggggggg label yall                           

   VAR3                        LAB3                           Type1      

   VAR4                        LAB4                           Type1      
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Or if you will have several tables with the same problem, specify the `split` value once:

```
> panderOptions('table.split.table', Inf)
> pander(data)

-------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Variable                      Label                      Classification 
---------- --------------------------------------------- ----------------
   VAR1                        LABEL                          Type1      

   VAR2                       A very                          Type2      
           loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo                 
              ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo                    
                    nnnnnnngggggggg label yall                           

   VAR3                        LAB3                           Type1      

   VAR4                        LAB4                           Type1      
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

In short, look for the `table.split.table` and `table.split.cells` [global options](http://rapporter.github.io/pander/#general-options), although there are a bunch of other useful tweaks as well.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the suggestion. This works for the oversized table, but what about the smaller table, any ideas on how to stretch that out to the page width? I looked through the link you sent me (very helpful) but could not find much on how I might extend the small tables width.

Comment: @decal this is not a `kable`, and not even related to `markdown`. The PDF table is rendered by Pandoc/pdflatex, which uses a LaTeX template, and the HTLM file also uses another (CSS) stylesheet. If you want to have similar or the exact same output, then you have to tweak those and [call Pandoc accordingly](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#general-writer-options). For more details, see the [related docs of Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/demo/example9/templates.html). I hope it  helps.